# Calculate correlation between two variables on two different scales by class

Tags: r, correlation

I combined two data set with three variables: class, total1, total2. total1 is the individual average score for each student, total2 is the average of the teacher's assessment for each class. The average score on two different scales.

```
df
    class   total1   total2
    A       4.9      6.7
    A       3.8      6.7
    A       4.2      6.7
    B       4.5      7.2
    B       3.9      7.2 
    B       4.1      7.2
    C       3.5      6.5
    C       4.4      6.5
    C       3.6      6.5
```

I want to calculate the correlation between total1 and total2 with r and p-value. I used this code but I was not able to get the average score of total1 by class:

```
library("ggpubr")
ggscatter(df, x = "total2", y = "total1", 
          add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "spearman",
          xlab = "Teacher score", ylab = "Student score")
```

Comment: Am I correct that there are three distinct classes, each having three distinct students and with a separate teacher per class?

Comment: can you post `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dplyr library.

```
library(dplyr)

class <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
total1 <- c(4.9, 3.8, 4.2, 4.5, 3.9, 4.1, 3.5, 4.4, 3.6)
total2 <- c(6.7, 6.7, 6.7, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5)

df <- data.frame(class,total1,total2)
sum_data <- df %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  summarise(total1_mean=mean(total1),total2_mean=mean(total2))

sum_data

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  class total1_mean total2_mean
#  <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 A            4.3          6.7
#2 B            4.17         7.2
#3 C            3.83         6.5



res <- cor.test(sum_data$total1_mean,sum_data$total2_mean) 
res

#Pearson's product-moment correlation

#data:  sum_data$total1_mean and sum_data$total2_mean
#t = 0.57735, df = 1, p-value = 0.6667
#alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
#sample estimates:
#cor 
#0.5

res$p.value #[1] 0.6666667 
res$estimate #cor 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s <- "class   total1   total2
    A       4.9      6.7
    A       3.8      6.7
    A       4.2      6.7
    B       4.5      7.2
    B       3.9      7.2 
    B       4.1      7.2
    C       3.5      6.5
    C       4.4      6.5
    C       3.6      6.5
"

df <- read.table(text=s, header=TRUE)
dfs <- split(df, df$class)

avg_m <- t(sapply(dfs, function(df) colMeans(df[, -1])))
res <- cor.test(x=avg_m[,"total1"], y=avg_m[, "total2"])
res$estimate ## 0.5
res$p.value  ## [1] 0.6666667
```